# Why is my UIButton not clickable after updating the ImageView above it?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview, uistoryboard

I created my app's home page via the Storyboard. I have had no issues in the past, even when I added the blank ImageView above the UIButton.  Only when I update the ImageView using the code below, the UIButton immediately below it becomes unclickable. It doesn't even highlight upon pressing.  They are set up with a vertical space constraint, targeting the UIButton, allowing 20px of space.  There is no visual overlapping.  Here's the code I'm using to update the image:

```
foodImage.image = UIImage(named: "Closed.jpg")
```

Here's a screenshot of my storyboard as well:

[image: picture of the storyboard]

This is my first question, so if you need any more info let me know. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked that the outlet and action of uibutton is not deleted?

Comment: try self.view.bringSubviewToFront(button), After you update your image, and also check is button.isEnabled ? and if possible show your View hierarchy

Comment: what kind of content mode that you  have set in UIImageView?

Comment: @iOSGeek I tried the self.view.bringSubviewToFront and it still didn't work. I'm just going to hide the image altogether in these situations and work around it. I appreciate all you guys' help though.

Comment: Can you share the Xcode File ? so I can look why this is Happening

Answer (score 0):

the default value UIImageView's property userInteractionEnabled is false. you can try set it to true.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not attempting to click on the ImageView, just the UIButton.